# MS ACCESS - MYSQL personalized sync

Tags: mysql, ms-access, database-connection

I have to connect two existing databases: a ms access one (Access 2010) stored on al local server (Windows Server 2008 R2) and used by my company, which can't be modified in the structure except to add new fields (my collegues absolutely don't want to change); and a mysql one stored on a server on-line and from which the data are picked up by a PHP program (this means that it would be very onerous to change the structure for me). The structure of these two databases is similar but not completely identical: for example i need to put the data of two tables of the access into only one of the mysql, and the names of the fields are completely different from a database to another. Can anyone suggest me a software to connect and synchronize them (even once a hour)? I know there are several options like ODBC connector offered directly from mysql.com but i've had problems installing it, and I've also tried that: https://dbconvert.com/mysql/access/ but it seems to not support my version of access db so I wasn't able to understand if these two solutions were adaptable to my situation. Does someone who has faced a similar problem and who is more experienced than me suggest an easy solution? Should I try harder with the two "solutions" i mentioned? Sorry for the ignorance, I trust you :)

Answer (score 0):

Have an Access file use linked tables to the Access DB and linked tables via ODBC to MySQL, this method works well. Look into improving your ODBC Connection.
I found the 32 bit version of ODBC to MySQL gave me better results, linking from Access 2003.